# Mist coming out vent and water leaking under dash

Tags: ac

When I turn on ac after a while a mist starts coming out and I have a leak under dash  for about a month now.

What can it be?

Please help

Answer (score 6):

A blocked drain pipe below the A/C evaporator in the passenger compartment would cause this.  Directly beneath the dash underneath the car you will probably find a couple of open-ended pipes that are meant to drain condensation from the A/C system.  These are probably blocked so the condensation is building up and leaking into the passenger compartment.  Use a drinking straw or something similar to poke the pipes clear, don't use anything sharp or hard that could damage the A/C internals.

Comment: Often accompanied by a "running water" sound or "sloshing water when turning"...

Comment: I agree with your analysis, but would suggest using a long thin wire to get the drain unblocked. The distance from the opening to the blockage can sometimes be a bit. Also, something stiff is going to work much better than something which will flex.